# Search in group of records, joined by field, using ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

I have `User` (administration), `Seller`, `Customer` and `Payment` models. When customer buys something, two payment will be created - one from customer to seller and one from seller two system (website takes a percentage of each purchase). Those two payments have identical value in `identifier` filed, so they are in one "purchase group". So each purchase creates separate "purchase group" with two payments, grouped together by `identifier`. Let's look at one "purchase group":

```
#<Payment
 id: "1",
 user_id: "5",
 amount: 100.0,
 created_at: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 19:33:49 +03 +03:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 19:33:49 +03 +03:00,
 transaction_id: "18Y123451Y261315X",
 identifier: "b7d93d89">

#<Payment
 id: "2",
 user_id: "1",
 amount: 2.0,
 created_at: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 19:34:21 +03 +03:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 10 Nov 2017 19:34:21 +03 +03:00,
 transaction_id: "0L052241XU999721E",
 identifier: "b7d93d89">
```

So first `Payment` goes to seller with `user_id: "5"` and second one to the system (main admin with `user_id: "1"`). And they have identical `identifier: "b7d93d89"`.

Each seller can open special table in his profile, where he could see all received money (all payments with `user_id: "5"`) and he could search by `transaction_id`, BUT only by his own `transaction_id`, that stored in payments with `user_id: "5"`.

I need to create ransacker for search by any `transaction_id` in "purchase group", so seller could use `transaction_id: "0L052241XU999721E"` from another payment in the same "purchase group" and find his own payment.

For now, I don`t have any ideas. Maybe somebody could help me? Thanks.